# cross collection query in mongoose with $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am building a question-answers database. I have three schemas, User, Question and Replies(answers). My problem begins where I want to query just the questions that the user has not already answered. but when I run this query I get the question with an empty replies array. should I populate it somehow? here's where I got:

Query:

```
let getQuestions = (req, res)=>{

    Question.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {isGlobal: true}
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'Reply',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'questionID',
                as: 'replies'
            }
        },
        // {
        //     $match: {}
        // }
    ]).then(foundQuestions=> console.log(foundQuestions))
};
```

User Schema (simplified):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    questionReplies: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Reply'
        }
    ],
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Question Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const questionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    description: String,
    isGlobal: Boolean,
    options: [
        {
            number: Number,
            title: String,
        }
    ]
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Question', questionSchema);
```

Reply Schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const replySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    questionID: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Question',
        required: true
    },
    email: {type: String, required: true},
    answerID: {type: String, required: true},
    number: Number,
    title: String,
}, {timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Reply', replySchema);
```

my replies collection has this document inside:

```
"questionID" : ObjectId("5c6f6867cbff9c2a9004eb6d")
```

and I have a question with this ID:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5c6f6867cbff9c2a9004eb6d"),
```

(any opnions on improving database design are welcome too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem and I post here for future references.

the `from` field used in `$lookup` refers to the **collection name** created by mongodb, not the **Model name** used in mongoose. So the correct query is:

```
$lookup: {
    from: 'replies',
    localField: '_id',
    foreignField: 'questionID',
    as: 'replies'
}
```

and then I added

```
{
    $match: { "replies": { $eq: [] } }
}
```

for finding just the questions with no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
let getQuestions = (req, res)=>{
    Question.aggregate([
        {
            $match: {isGlobal: true}
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'Reply',
                localField: '_id',
                foreignField: 'questionID',
                as: 'replies'
            }
        },
        {
             $match: { "replies": { $eq: [] } }
        }
    ]).then(foundQuestions=> console.log(foundQuestions))
};
```

So you will get question which does not have any replies.

Comment: I also think this should work, but before the last ```$match``` the ```$lookup``` returns an empty replies array. I think the last match won't do anything on it. but I'll give it a try.

Comment: You are getting questions with empty replies array that means such questions hadn't any answered by any user yet. I guess that was your desired result as you said above "I want to query just the questions that the user has not already answered".

Comment: but there is a reply for that question, that's the problem. the ```$lookup``` should return questions with the replies populated in them, then the last ```$match``` will choose the ones that do not have replies. but I get the replies array empty, even now that i have a reply for that question in my db.